# Whats wrong with this form routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a users model and a book model. Users can read books (as a reader) which creates an entry in the Readings model:

```
id | reader_id | book_id
```

Users also have a list of books that they have read. These are stored in the Red (I use Red because the present and past tense of the word 'read' are the same) model which looks the same as the Reading model above.

Now when a user is reading a book, I would like to display a button which represents finishing the book.

The finish action is in the ReadingsController and looks like this:

```
def finish
  @book = current_user.readings.find(params[:id]).book
  current_user.stop_reading!(@book)
  current_user.make_red! @book

  redirect_to :back
end
```

As you can probably tell, this takes in the id of a record in the readings table, destroys it and makes a new record in the table for recording books red.

The form helper for the "Finish Reading" button currently looks like this:

```
<%= form_for :reading, current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id), :url => { :controller => :readings, :action => "finish" }, :method => :delete do |f| %>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit button_text %></div>
<% end %>
```

But for some reason this renders a form with the wrong id because "9781440506604" is not the id of a record in the readings table, it's the id of a record in the books table (the ISBN-13 of a book to be precise).

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/readings/9781440506604/finish" method="post">
</form>
```

What is it I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** to add reading.rb

```
class Reading < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_id

  # one person reading a new book may cause feed_item creations in multiple users feeds
  has_many :feed_items, :as => :event
  has_many :comments, :as => :parent, :dependent => :destroy

  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  # need to pass the class name here because there is no Reader model
  belongs_to :reader, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :book

  validates :reader_id, :presence => true
  validates :book_id, :presence => true

  def self.followed_by(user)
    ...
  end
end

# and user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar, :remember_me, :avatar_url
has_many :readings, :dependent => :destroy,
                      :foreign_key => "reader_id"
  has_many :reads, :through => :readings, :source => :book
  has_many :reds, :foreign_key => "reader_id",
                  :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :red, :through => :reds, :source => :book

  def reading? book
    self.readings.find_by_book_id(book)
  end

  def read! book
    self.readings.create!(:book_id => book.id)
  end

  def stop_reading! book
    self.readings.find_by_book_id(book).destroy
  end

  def red? book
    self.reds.find_by_book_id(book)
  end

  def make_red! book
    unless red? book
      self.reds.create!(:book_id => book.id)
    end
  end
end
```

By the way I tried making a user who is reading book 1 and doing user.readings.find_by_book_id(1) in the console and it returns a record from the readings table.

as requested

```
# routes.rb
resources :readings, :only => [:create, :destroy, :show] do
  member do
    post :create_comment
    delete :finish
  end
end
```

Comment: and user model will be useful too

Comment: Added the relevant parts of the user model and the results of a check I did in the console.

Comment: what is this: `has_many :readings, :foreign_key => "reader_id"` and at the top you told that reading is: `id | user_id | book_id`. there is no `reader_id`

Comment: Yeah I said user_id at the top (before I knew I'd be posting my reader model) but the column's real name is reader_id. The line :class_name => "User" takes care of the association. I'll add routes to the OP now in a sec. I'll edit the schema I posted too.

Comment: everything looks fine. try this `<%= form_for :reading, current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id), :url => { :controller => :readings, :action => "finish", :id => current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id).id }, :method => :delete do |f| %>`

Comment: and just try to debug this `<%= current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id).inspect %>`

Comment: Ok the inspection gives: #<Reading id: 31, reader_id: 1, book_id: 11, created_at: "2011-04-06 16:22:23", updated_at: "2011-04-06 16:22:23">
The form action appears to render correctly now but I get a routing error when I click the button: No route matches "/readings/31/finish". This is odd though because I opened up the console and there is definitely a reading record with ID = 31. Any further ideas? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: remove `:only => [:create, :destroy, :show]` from your routes

Comment: That didn't fix it I'm afraid. I inspected the request headers in firebug though and it seems that it's actually sending a PUT request when I click the "I'm finished" button for some reason, even though I've specified delete. I get the impression that for some reason rails thinks I want to edit the book (that would help explain the book id being in the URL by default). In fact, if I change the route from delete to put, the action seems to work perfectly. So weird. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: wrapyour `:method => :delete` into `:html => {}` => `<%= form_for :reading, current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id), :url => { :controller => :readings, :action => "finish", :id => current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id).id }, :html => {:method => :delete} do |f| %>`

Comment: Yep! That did it. Thank you very much, you basically just walked me through the whole solution. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have got `to_param` method in your `Reading` model

try to call id clearly:

```
current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id).id
```

**UPD**

1. remove `:only => [:create, :destroy, :show]` from your routes
2. use this `<%= form_for :reading, current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id), :url => { :controller => :readings, :action => "finish", :id => current_user.readings.find_by_book_id(book.id).id }, :html => {:method => :delete} do |f| %>`

Comment: There's no to_param in there. I do have a to_param in my book model so that ISBM-13 is the default identifier rather than id but that shouldn't make a difference since I'm using book.id explicitly here. I tried your code anyway but I just get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly knowledgeable about rails 3 (still using rails 2), but shouldn't you be passing more information to the `:url` param?

This doesn't seem to mention anything about the ID you want to post to:

```
:url => { :controller => :readings, :action => "finish" }
```

Shouldn't it be something closer to this:

```
:url => { :controller => :readings, :action => "finish", :id => reading_id }
```

(Assuming `reading_id` to be substituted for the actual ID)